# Problems with Reflection on winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I have a winforms application.

I have a Populate method that creates a bunch of controls on each page on my tabcontrol. The Populate method takes two arguments - the tab page and a List with the strings for a bunch of labels. There is a separate List for each tabpage and the names of the Lists are the same as the names of the tabpages. I want to iterate through the pages and pass the appropriate List to the Populate method by name, i.e. to pass the List by a string that is its name. As far as I know I need Reflection for that.

Code:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> Hongdoe = new List<string>(new string[] { "Chin", "Foa", "Hu", "Dan" });
        List<string> Donfu = new List<string>(new string[] { "Faa", "Su", "Pi", "Mou" });
        //TabPage1.Name = Hongdoe
        //TabPage2.Name = Donfu
        foreach (TabPage tp in Tab_Control.TabPages)
        {
            //I want to tell the program "Find the variable/list that is named as 'tp.Name'
            var ListName = typeof(Form1).GetField(tp.Name)
            Populate(tp, ListName);
        }


    }

    void Populate (TabPage tp, List<string> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            //Create labels
            Label lab = new Label();
            lab.Text = list[i];
            lab.Location = new Point(i * 10, i * 10));
            tp.Controls.Add(lab);
        }
    }
}
```

But sofar it returns null. I also tried using "GetProperty", "GetValue" but no success.

(before I edited this question I used a variable to demonstrate my problem simply)

Comment: This doesn't sound like the right use for reflection. Can you give some more context as to what you need to be able to do?

Comment: Please note that "variable", "property" and "field" are very different concepts in C#. Classes don't have variables - please show [MCVE] that would clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use reflection. You can use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and use list names (tab page names) as keys and list of strings as values. Then you can get a list using the key from dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
private void ProductList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Initialize dictionary with keys and values
    dictionary["page1"] = new List<string> { "string 1", "string 2" };
    dictionary["page2"] = new List<string> { "string 3", "string 4" };
    //...
}
```

Then you can call your `Populate` method this way:

```
Populate(tp, dictionary[tp.Name]);
```

Note

- You don't need to pass list to the method and it's enough to pass `TabPage` to the method and you can get the list using `dictionary[tabPage.Name]`
- You can use a `TableLayoutPanel` or a `FlowLayoutPanel` in tab pages to add labels to. This way they will be arranged automatically.
- Just for learning purpose if you want to use reflection:

  ```
  var list = (List<string>)this.GetType().GetField("Hongdoe", 
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this);
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However, I would still prefer to do it with reflection, at the very least I would like to learn to use reflection. But I will certainly look into TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel!

Comment: You are welcome. No problem, you can learn reflection, but after you learned how to use reflection, come back and use dictionary instead, because it's the way you should go for this problem.

Comment: @mathgenius Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I just haven't had the time to write anything, yet. I'll let you know when I try it out.

Comment: So the reflection works, but let me be sure - the "Instance" binding flag is set to denote we are searching in the currently executing instance, correct? Also, I suppose the "NonPublic" flag is needed since my List<string> is not set with the "Public" property? Additionally, why do we tell it "GetValue(this)"? Isn't "this" the form and how does it tie in with the "GetValue" method, especially when I thought "GetValue" would return a value, for example the string at the first position in the list.

Comment: **1-** You must specify `Instance` or `Static` along with `Public` or `NonPublic` or no members will be returned. So I used `NonPublic | Instance` because your field is not static and is not public. **2-** You have a field so we should use `GetField`, for properties we use `GetProperty`. **3-** I used `GetValue(this)` because the field belongs to `this`. So when you found `SomeFiled` using reflection calling `GetValue(this)` against the field is equivalent to `this.SomeFiled`, It will return value of the field which is `List<string>` here and you can cast it to `List<string>`

Comment: [BindingFlags Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) has more description about different binding flags like `Public`, `NonPublic`, `Static`, ....